# MVC 4 Variables in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 3 I was able to put:

```
@{
    string rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
    if (rootPath == "/")
    {
        rootPath = rootPath.Replace("/", "");
    }
}
```

in my _Layout.cshtml file and then use rootPath in any of my other views to get the site root.
I tried the same thing in a MVC 4 app and it doesn't work unless I put the above code in the same view file I'm trying to use rootPath in. 
Has anyone else bumped into this issue?

Comment: Use `ViewBag`, and your `if` statement seems a little redundant, why bother calling `.Replace()` when you already know the input.  That could simply be:

    if (rootPath == "/")
    {
        rootPath = string.Empty;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing, you can just put that logic in an html helper which can then be called from anywhere.